# TabLayout With WebServices[API]

Tags: android, fragment, android-tablayout

I am trying to populate a recyclerview inside the Fragment under a TabLayout. Everything seems to be fine, but the data is not actually populated in the recyclerview, while all the content Logs[Log.e();] is working fine. Can anyone relate the issue ?

My Fragment Is Like :

```
public class SugarLevelReport extends Fragment
{
private ConstraintLayout view_constraintLayout;
private RecyclerView blood_sugar_recyclerView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private ArrayList<PatientRecordModel> patientRecordModelArrayList = new ArrayList<PatientRecordModel>();
private RecyclerView.Adapter bloodSugaradapter;

// for intent data
public String patient_id_from_intent, patient_name_from_intent, patient_dob_from_intent, patient_mobile_from_intent, patient_email_from_intent;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sugar_level_report, container, false);

    findViewById(view);
    return view;  
}
public void findViewById(View view)
{
    view_constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.view_constraintLayout);
    /*progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);*/
    blood_sugar_recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.blood_sugar_recyclerView);

    blood_sugar_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    blood_sugar_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    bloodSugaradapter = new SugarLevelReportAdapter(getActivity(), patientRecordModelArrayList);
    blood_sugar_recyclerView.setAdapter(bloodSugaradapter);

    loadData();
}
public void loadData()
{
    if(GlobalMethods.isNetworkConnected(getActivity()))
    {

        String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++)
        {
            PatientRecordModel patientRecordModel = new PatientRecordModel();
            patientRecordModel.setPatient_name(names[i]);

            // log here is working fine , and its giving correct data
            Log.e("patientsName", patientRecordModel.getPatient_name());

            patientRecordModelArrayList.add(patientRecordModel);
            bloodSugaradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class SugarLevelReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SugarLevelReportAdapter.SugarLevelReportHolder>{
public Context context;
public ArrayList<PatientRecordModel> patientRecordModelArrayList = new ArrayList<PatientRecordModel>();

public SugarLevelReportAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PatientRecordModel> patientRecordModelArrayList)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.patientRecordModelArrayList = patientRecordModelArrayList;
}
@Override
public SugarLevelReportHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sugar_level_report_cardview, parent, false);
    SugarLevelReportHolder sugarLevelReportHolder = new SugarLevelReportHolder(view);
    return sugarLevelReportHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SugarLevelReportHolder holder, int position)
{
    PatientRecordModel patientRecordModel = patientRecordModelArrayList.get(position);

    Log.e("patient_name",patientRecordModel.getPatient_name());
    holder.patient_name_textView.setText(patientRecordModel.getPatient_name());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return patientRecordModelArrayList.size();
}
public static class SugarLevelReportHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView month_textView, date_textView, year_textView;
    public TextView patient_name_textView, patient_count_textView, meal_type_textView;
    public ImageView overflow_menu_imageView;
    public SugarLevelReportHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        month_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.month_textView);
        date_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_textView);
        year_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.year_textView);
        patient_name_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.patient_name_textView);
        patient_count_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.patient_count_textView);
        meal_type_textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.meal_type_textView);
        overflow_menu_imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.overflow_menu_imageView);
    }
}
```

}

xml code [fragment_sugar_level_report.xml]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/blood_sugar_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a similar problem on my current project. I cannot tell you why it happens but to solve it you need to move the part for updating data to the adapter. 
on your adapter create the following method:

```
public void updateData(List<PatientRecordModel> list){
   patientRecordModelArrayList  = list;
   notifyDatasetChanged();
  }
```

On you Fragment class  when you want to update the data just call

```
bloodSugaradapter.updateData(patientRecordModel);
```

On the same it is advisable to load your views onViewCreated instead of onCreateView. Also use a data mapping library such as GSON or or jackson to improve speed and reliability in data mapping.See a comparison [here](https://medium.com/@dannydamsky99/heres-why-you-probably-shouldn-t-be-using-the-gson-library-in-2018-4bed5698b78b)  Hope this helps

Comment: Can you provide some examples or links related to GSON or jackson to improve speed and reliability in data mapping? It would be a great support. Thanks

Comment: I have added the link in the post. If the answer worked for you do you mind marking it as answer to help others in the future